File selector-Box for getting links to files in Intranet-Filesystems
i develop a blazor server-application with following requirements:

The user wants to to save links to files (e.g. d:\temp\test.doc or \shareserver\share\test.doc) or directories (e.g. d:\temp or \shareserver\share)
to a database.
The user should be able to select those files and directories in the file-system with a file-selector box and get the path to them.

The standard html -Element is not working because it is not publishing the path to the selected file.
Is there any solution for this?
best regards
Volkhard

This strikes me as a serious violation of basic security.  I recommend making a separate API to serve the files, and allow selection only by file name, description, date, etc.  Or just make an FTP server.

Hello @Bennyboy1973: thanks for your comment. why this requirement violates basic security? I´ve read in many articles that this is for security reason- but i didn´t found a reasonable explaination for this ...

A browser should be a sandbox.  There should be no way, programmatically, to access any "real" files directly in the file system.  Imagine if you were on the internet, and someone was running such a webpage!

You can do this through a js method. When the user selects a file, bind a js method to get the file path. Use the DotNet.invokeMethodAsync method to pass the file path to the backend:
function getFilePath() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    document.getElementById('filePath').innerText = filePath;
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorApp21', 'ReceiveFilePath', filePath);
}

Note:
BlazorApp21 is the name of my sample project. You should change it to a suitable name in your project.
Viewcomponent:
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="getFilePath()" />
<p id="filePath"></p>

@code {
    [JSInvokable]
    public static void ReceiveFilePath(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Selected file path: {path}");
       //save to database

    }
}

When I select a local image file, the image path will be obtained:


Hello @Yning Duan,
thanks for this. i always get the c:\fakepath-path. I there a way to turn it off for the edge browser?

Since the Edge browser security policy will change the path to c:\\fakepath-path and the file name, if you want to get the full path, you can enable IE mode in the Edge browser and add the relevant URL to the Internet Explorer mode pages, and then go to browser settings/Default browser/Internet Option/Security/Custom/find the Include local directory path When uploading files to a server and Enable. This will get the full path.
But it should be noted that this method will affect security
